# Why when the camera is child of the character only when pressing on W to move forward the character is not moving and everything is stuttering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Camera Settings]

This is the character settings and components :

[image: Character Settings]

The character don't move and everything stuttering only when the Camera is child of the character.
If the camera is not child of the character the character will move fine but I want the camera to follow the character.

Maybe I should edit and add the ThirdPersonCharacter script ? It's attached to the character. The script is a bit long.

There are 3 scripts they are all connected a bit long but they are all making the character controlling.

ThirdPersonUserControl :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class ThirdPersonUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ThirdPersonCharacter m_Character; // A reference to the ThirdPersonCharacter on the object
        private Transform m_Cam;                  // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
        private Vector3 m_CamForward;             // The current forward direction of the camera
        private Vector3 m_Move;
        private bool m_Jump;                      // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.

        
        private void Start()
        {
            // get the transform of the main camera
            if (Camera.main != null)
            {
                m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(
                    "Warning: no main camera found. Third person character needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.", gameObject);
                // we use self-relative controls in this case, which probably isn't what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
            }

            // get the third person character ( this should never be null due to require component )
            m_Character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }
        }


        // Fixed update is called in sync with physics
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // read inputs
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

            // calculate move direction to pass to character
            if (m_Cam != null)
            {
                // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                m_Move = v*m_CamForward + h*m_Cam.right;
            }
            else
            {
                // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                m_Move = v*Vector3.forward + h*Vector3.right;
            }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // walk speed multiplier
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

            // pass all parameters to the character control script
            m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
            m_Jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

AICharacterControl :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class AICharacterControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent { get; private set; }             // the navmesh agent required for the path finding
        public ThirdPersonCharacter character { get; private set; } // the character we are controlling
        public Transform target;                                    // target to aim for


        private void Start()
        {
            // get the components on the object we need ( should not be null due to require component so no need to check )
            agent = GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
            character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

            agent.updateRotation = false;
            agent.updatePosition = true;
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (target != null)
                agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (agent.remainingDistance > agent.stoppingDistance)
                character.Move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
            else
                character.Move(Vector3.zero, false, false);
        }


        public void SetTarget(Transform target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }
    }
}
```

ThirdPersonCharacter :

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
        [SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
        [SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
        [Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
        [SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
        [SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

        Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
        Animator m_Animator;
        bool m_IsGrounded;
        float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
        const float k_Half = 0.5f;
        float m_TurnAmount;
        float m_ForwardAmount;
        Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
        float m_CapsuleHeight;
        Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
        CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
        bool m_Crouching;


        void Start()
        {
            m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
            m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
            m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

            m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
            m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;
        }


        public void Move(Vector3 move, bool crouch, bool jump)
        {

            // convert the world relative moveInput vector into a local-relative
            // turn amount and forward amount required to head in the desired
            // direction.
            if (move.magnitude > 1f) move.Normalize();
            move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
            CheckGroundStatus();
            move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, m_GroundNormal);
            m_TurnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
            m_ForwardAmount = move.z;

            ApplyExtraTurnRotation();

            // control and velocity handling is different when grounded and airborne:
            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                HandleGroundedMovement(crouch, jump);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleAirborneMovement();
            }

            ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(crouch);
            PreventStandingInLowHeadroom();

            // send input and other state parameters to the animator
            UpdateAnimator(move);
        }


        void ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(bool crouch)
        {
            if (m_IsGrounded && crouch)
            {
                if (m_Crouching) return;
                m_Capsule.height = m_Capsule.height / 2f;
                m_Capsule.center = m_Capsule.center / 2f;
                m_Crouching = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
                float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
                {
                    m_Crouching = true;
                    return;
                }
                m_Capsule.height = m_CapsuleHeight;
                m_Capsule.center = m_CapsuleCenter;
                m_Crouching = false;
            }
        }

        void PreventStandingInLowHeadroom()
        {
            // prevent standing up in crouch-only zones
            if (!m_Crouching)
            {
                Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
                float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
                {
                    m_Crouching = true;
                }
            }
        }


        void UpdateAnimator(Vector3 move)
        {
            // update the animator parameters
            m_Animator.SetFloat("Forward", m_ForwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            m_Animator.SetFloat("Turn", m_TurnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            m_Animator.SetBool("Crouch", m_Crouching);
            m_Animator.SetBool("OnGround", m_IsGrounded);
            if (!m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_Animator.SetFloat("Jump", m_Rigidbody.velocity.y);
            }

            // calculate which leg is behind, so as to leave that leg trailing in the jump animation
            // (This code is reliant on the specific run cycle offset in our animations,
            // and assumes one leg passes the other at the normalized clip times of 0.0 and 0.5)
            float runCycle =
                Mathf.Repeat(
                    m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime + m_RunCycleLegOffset, 1);
            float jumpLeg = (runCycle < k_Half ? 1 : -1) * m_ForwardAmount;
            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_Animator.SetFloat("JumpLeg", jumpLeg);
            }

            // the anim speed multiplier allows the overall speed of walking/running to be tweaked in the inspector,
            // which affects the movement speed because of the root motion.
            if (m_IsGrounded && move.magnitude > 0)
            {
                m_Animator.speed = m_AnimSpeedMultiplier;
            }
            else
            {
                // don't use that while airborne
                m_Animator.speed = 1;
            }
        }


        void HandleAirborneMovement()
        {
            // apply extra gravity from multiplier:
            Vector3 extraGravityForce = (Physics.gravity * m_GravityMultiplier) - Physics.gravity;
            m_Rigidbody.AddForce(extraGravityForce);

            m_GroundCheckDistance = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 ? m_OrigGroundCheckDistance : 0.01f;
        }


        void HandleGroundedMovement(bool crouch, bool jump)
        {
            // check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
            if (jump && !crouch && m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Grounded"))
            {
                // jump!
                m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x, m_JumpPower, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
                m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
            }
        }

        void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
        {
            // help the character turn faster (this is in addition to root rotation in the animation)
            float turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(m_StationaryTurnSpeed, m_MovingTurnSpeed, m_ForwardAmount);
            transform.Rotate(0, m_TurnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }


        public void OnAnimatorMove()
        {
            // we implement this function to override the default root motion.
            // this allows us to modify the positional speed before it's applied.
            if (m_IsGrounded && Time.deltaTime > 0)
            {
                Vector3 v = (m_Animator.deltaPosition * m_MoveSpeedMultiplier) / Time.deltaTime;

                // we preserve the existing y part of the current velocity.
                v.y = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y;
                m_Rigidbody.velocity = v;
            }
        }


        void CheckGroundStatus()
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            // helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
#endif
            // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
            // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
            {
                m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
                m_IsGrounded = true;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the script ThirdPersonCharacter there is no Update function at all.

In the AICharacterControl there is Update I tried to change it to FixedUpdate but it didn't fix the problem.

In the script ThirdPersonUserControl there is Update but it's only for Jump and there is also FixedUpdate so I didn't try to change anything in that script.

Answer (score 2):

Try using FixedUpdate() instead of Update() and see. Also, you should at least post the relevant bit of code.

Comment: I edited my question added some code and explained where and what I tried. So far no success of fixing the problem.

Comment: Do you have a background or anything else in the scene? If you attach the camera to directly to the character object, then they share the same reference frame. That means that even when the object is moving in the global coordinate system, relative to the camera, it will not move. Do they x,y,z coordinates of the player change?